# JHipster deployment displays the openshift default project page

Tags: java, angularjs, jhipster

The `Jhipster` deployment of my application to `Openshift` is displaying the default `Openshift` html page instead of my application main html page, any idea of what is causing this?

Openshift html page = the page that you see when you create a default java application in Openshift.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: could you add more info to your question, like are you using the openshift deploy generator from the jhispter guide?

Comment: Well I am using the version that is before 2.0, and I am using the openshift deploy generator from the jhipster guide.